# How do I decode/parse the Access and ID tokens returned to me by Cognito?

Tags: javascript, json, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I have gotten to the following two lines in my javascript code:

```
alert(result.getAccessToken().getJwtToken());
alert(result.getIdToken().getJwtToken());
```

I now want to get the family_name value from the payload of th ID token, as well as the expiration time of the token, but am a little confused. I know the tokens are JSON Web Tokens but I am still a little confused as to how to easily access these values (eg family_name) that are part of the JSON Web Token payload?!
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [this example](https://github.com/aws/amazon-cognito-identity-js/blob/master/src/CognitoIdToken.js#L51), a function in AWS Cognito JS SDK; it parses JWT to read token expiry. A JWT has three parts (header, payload and signature - in that order), which are separated by "**.**". The payload is encoded as UTF-8 chars in base 64. To read the claims from the payload, extract the payload and convert it into a JSON object. Read the claims that you are interested in from the JSON object, for e.g. get expiry by ***payloadJsonObject.exp***.